# PowerShell ForEach $file in $Files

Tags: powershell, foreach

I have a PowerShell script that gets a file listing and moves the files that meet a specific criteria. Why does the `foreach` loop run even if the object is empty?

I would assume if $i did not exist it would not run. But if there are no results in $filePath why does the forEach loop run once? I have worked around my issue, but I am curious and I tried searching, but I could not find the answer.

To get this to work I just check to make sure $filePath exists before the forEach loop.

For example, if ($filePath){...

```
 $filePath = Get-ChildItem -Path $sourceDir | Where-Object {! $_.PSIsContainer -AND ($_.Name -Match "^XXX_XXX*" -OR $_.Name -Match "^YYY_XX*")}

 ForEach($i in $filePath){
     $sfName =  $i.Name
     $sfDir = $i.Directory
     $tFileName = testFile $destDir $sfName
     $sFile = $sourceDir + $sfName
     $tFile = $destDir + $tFileName

     moveFile $sFile $tFile
```

Answer (score 63, accepted):

This is a classic issue that has been fixed in PowerShell V3 IIRC.  PowerShell's `foreach` loop will allow you to iterate over a scalar value e.g.:

```
foreach ($i in 1) {$i}
```

That is handy because many times the collection you iterate can contain 0, 1 or N items e.g.:

```
$files = Get-ChildItem c:\temp\*.txt
foreach ($file in $files) {$file}
```

In this case, `Get-ChildItem` could return 0, 1 or N files. N files is great, we can iterate over that.  However if it returned 1 file and then you had to stick that one file in an array so that you could use `foreach` - well that would kind of suck.  So `foreach` allows you to iterate over a scalar object.  The problem occurs when `Get-ChildItem` returns 0 objects.  In that case, an empty array is not assigned to $files.  Instead $null is assigned. PowerShell considers $null a scalar and hence the `foreach` loop will execute once where the iterated value is $null. That kind of sucks.  And I and many other folks told the team this early on, so in V3 they changed `foreach` to not iterate a scalar if the value is $null.

Another way to work around this in V1/V2 is to ensure the empty case generates an empty array instead of $null.  You can do that using an `@()` array expression e.g.

```
$files = @(Get-ChildItem c:\temp\*.txt)
foreach ($file in $files) {$file}
```

This will work for 0, 1, and N files.  It's works for 0 files because the `@()` will result in an empty array being assigned to $files. `foreach` will not execute its body when looping over an empty array.

Comment: Thanks. I usually usually use powershell v3 but am writing scripts for some older severs that the powers that be do not want to up grade. This is one of those thing I am sure has been answered a thousand time but difficult to quantify in a search