# PowerShell and foreach loop

Tags: powershell

I'm working a PowerShell script to change the permissions for the "builtin users" group basically I need to add "modify" to one folder.  I need to do this to about 400 systems. My computer names are not showing up.

```
$computer = Get-Content -Path c:\computernames.txt
$user = "BUILTIN\Users" 
$Rights = "Modify","Synchronize" 
$InheritSettings = "Containerinherit, ObjectInherit"
$PropogationSettings = "None" 
$RuleType = "Allow" 

foreach ($computer in $computernames) {
    $path = "\\$computer\C$\Program Files (x86)\Directory1\Directory2"
    $acl = Get-Acl $path
    $perm = $user, $Rights, $InheritSettings, $PropogationSettings, $RuleType
    $rule = New-Object -TypeName System.Security.AccessControl.FileSystemAccessRule -ArgumentList $perm
    $acl.SetAccessRule($rule)
    $acl | Set-Acl -Path $path
}
```

I expect the code to run through all 400 names in a text file and change permissions.

Comment: `foreach($computersystem in $computer)`, you have get-content importing into `$computer` as well as the path looks incorrect, should be a string like "C:\ComputerNames.txt"

Comment: Possible duplicate of [PowerShell ForEach $file in $Files](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29440314/powershell-foreach-file-in-files)

Comment: Move ``$path = "\\$computer\C`$\Program Files (x86)\Directory1\Directory2"`` inside the `foreach` loop body.

Comment: Your path isn't quoted.

Comment: Does your updated code still not work? What does it actually do? Please provide more details.

Answer (score 0):

1st line was wrong....

$computer = Get-Content -Path c:\computernames.txt

do something like this..
$computernames= Get-Content -Path c:\computernames.txt

then you can loop the 400 computer and do require logic

[image]

also make sure you properly built the $path value , you will need to use + to join string...

Comment: Everyone Thanks for the Help !  I'm not sure what happened with the first line I shouldn't of cut & pasted my name change :(  Moving the path inside the loop seemed to helped   

@HO LI Pin I'm not sure what you mean by "you will need to use + to join string..."  is this correct $path = "\\$Computer\C$\Program Files (x86)\Directory1\Directory2" ? 
it seems to be working I need to do more testing 
@ Ansgar Wiechers The script basically adds "modify" rights for the BUILTIN\USERS group to one program folder d.