# How do I return a filename from a forEach-Object loop in Powershell?

Tags: powershell

I have been using Powershell for a day now and I need to return the file name for each file in a folder using a loop. Here is what I currently have:

```
$filePath = 'C:\Users\alibh\Desktop\Test Folder' #the path to the folder
cd $filePath

Get-ChildItem $filePath |
ForEach-Object{
$fileName = "here is where I return the name of each file so I can edit it 
later on"
}
```

I want to compare the names of the different files in the folder and edit or delete files later on; but before I can get to that, I first need to be able to get the name of each file one after another.

Edit: thanks a lot guys

Comment: You can access the currently iterated object with `$_` or `$PSiItem` and a specific property by appending it's name with a dot. `$_.FullName`, `$_.Name`, `$.BaseName` (Alternatively you can specify a `-PipeLineVariable` with the originating cmdlet)

Comment: You could try the answer found here: [PowerShell ForEach $file in $Files](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29440314/powershell-foreach-file-in-files?rq=1)

Answer (score 5):

For each filename only within your loop, you can do the following:

```
Get-ChildItem $filepath -File | Foreach-Object {
    $fileName = $_.Name
    $fileName   # Optional for returning the file name to the console
}
```

For each filename and its path only within your loop, you can do the following:

```
Get-ChildItem $filepath -File | Foreach-Object {
    $fileName = $_.FullName
}
```

**Explanation:**

With this code structure, you will only have access to each of those filenames within the `Foreach-Object` script block by default with the exception of the last object passed into the loop.
`$_` or `$PSItem` represents the current object within the `Foreach-Object {}` script block. It will contain all of the properties of a single object returned by `Get-ChildItem`. You can effectively see all of the properties accessible to the `$_` variable by either piping the `Get-ChildItem` results into `Get-Member` or the `$_` variable itself like so:

```
Get-ChildItem $filepath -File | Get-Member -MemberType Property

   TypeName: System.IO.FileInfo

Name              MemberType Definition
----              ---------- ----------
Attributes        Property   System.IO.FileAttributes Attributes {get;set;}
CreationTime      Property   datetime CreationTime {get;set;}
CreationTimeUtc   Property   datetime CreationTimeUtc {get;set;}
Directory         Property   System.IO.DirectoryInfo Directory {get;}
DirectoryName     Property   string DirectoryName {get;}
Exists            Property   bool Exists {get;}
Extension         Property   string Extension {get;}
FullName          Property   string FullName {get;}
IsReadOnly        Property   bool IsReadOnly {get;set;}
LastAccessTime    Property   datetime LastAccessTime {get;set;}
LastAccessTimeUtc Property   datetime LastAccessTimeUtc {get;set;}
LastWriteTime     Property   datetime LastWriteTime {get;set;}
LastWriteTimeUtc  Property   datetime LastWriteTimeUtc {get;set;}
Length            Property   long Length {get;}
Name              Property   string Name {get;}
```

Answer (score 2):

Here's an odd workaround to get the full path of each file (in a string context), add a wildcard to the folder path:

```
Get-ChildItem $filePath\* | ForEach { "$_" }
```